# Move Collections from TFS2010 to another TFS2010

Tags: team-foundation-server

We have followed- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869(v=vs.100).aspx every steps of this article for moving our collections on TFS2010 to another TFS2010 server. Everything is appeared successfully, but when we open visual studio and look project history we see that some user's names are likes "unknown identities(.........)". And also we look Group Membership on TFS Administration Console, there are some missing groups, users and etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solution is in this web site - Clone a TFS 2010 Instance From DB Backups – Quick and Dirty](http://www.andygeldman.com/index.php/2012/03/clone-a-tfs-2010-instance-from-db-backups-quick-and-dirty/)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you moved to a new server in a different Windows AD domain? If so, make sure the new domain has equivalent domain trust relationships as the old one.

Comment: Also new server is in a same AD domain with old machine. On the other hand ,When i restore backup collection, there isn't a Network Service account(nt authority\network service) in Project Collection Service Accounts. But if i create new collection there is a Network Service account(nt authority\network service). May be this cause my problem?